# another cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="someFile.json"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>


    <script >
    window.addEventListener('load', test, false);
    function test(){
        var name = document.getElementById(name);
        name.innerHTML = '<p>declaredArray[0].name</p>';
    }
    </script>


    <div id="name"></div>
    </header>
    <footer></footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have a JSON file with a declared array of objects. When I try to put certain content from this file on my web page via .innerHTML it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", although the declared array is in the scope and I can access it with console.log, for example.

Comment: What is `name` supposed to be in `document.getElementById(name)`? Did you mean `document.getElementById('name')`?

Comment: Omg. I Actually can't believe Iэму made this mistake. Thanks, man!